# TypeError: 'list' object is not callable - assertWarns()

Tags: python, python-unittest, assert

I have the following function:

```
def checking_remote_local_groups(data: List[dict], groups: List[dict]) -> List[dict]:
    step = 'GET_GROUPS_TO_CHECK'
    groups_to_check = []
    local_groups = [x['group'] for x in data]

    # Using set to get differences between local and AAD groups
    local_groups_set = set(local_groups)
   
    groups_set = set(x['name'] for x in groups)
    # If local AAD groups set are not in AAD groups, raise an Error on the workflow.
    if local_groups_set - groups_set:
        # SyncException is implemented somewhere.
        raise SyncException(
            f'{local_groups_set - groups_set} local group is not an AAD group\nCreate it via speckle-infra terraform',
            "We need to get in line, local and AAD groups. Additional {} group received from users.yaml".format(
                local_groups_set - groups_set
            ),
            step
        )
    # If remote groups set are not in local groups 
    if groups_set - local_groups_set:
        # Just notify it to the user
        warnings.warn(
            f"""
            {groups_set - local_groups_set} AAD group is not on users.yml as a local group
            Please add it if needed
            """
            )
    # If remote groups are the same than local groups
    elif local_groups_set == groups_set:
        print("AAD and local groups are inline"
            )
    return groups_to_check
```

I want to check the behavior of the second `if` section code (**If remote groups set are not in local groups**) by doing unittests using the assertWarns assertion, since I am triggering a warning in that case. So I have:

```
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_warning_checking_remote_group_not_in_local_groups(self):
        # local groups
        data = [{'group': 'foobar'}, {'group': 'test'}]
        
        # remote groups
        groups = [{'name': 'foobar'}, {'name': 'test'}, {'name': 'missing'}]
        self.assertWarns(
            UserWarning,
            checking_aad_local_groups(data, groups),
            [{"name": "missing"}]
        )
```

I got this output:

```
test_sync.py .F...........                                               [100%]

=================================== FAILURES ===================================
______ GroupsTestCase.test_warning_checking_aad_group_not_in_local_groups ______

self = <test_sync.GroupsTestCase testMethod=test_warning_checking_remote_group_not_in_local_groups>

    def test_warning_checking_remote_group_not_in_local_groups(self):
        data = [{'group': 'foobar'}, {'group': 'test'}]
        groups = [{'name': 'foobar'}, {'name': 'test'}, {'name': 'missing'}]
>       self.assertWarns(
            UserWarning,
            checking_aad_local_groups(data, groups),
            [{"name": "missing"}]
        )
E       TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

test_sync.py:158: TypeError
=============================== warnings summary ===============================
test_sync.py::GroupsTestCase::test_warning_checking_aad_group_not_in_local_groups
  /home/runner/work/speckle-user-management/speckle-user-management/groups.py:31: UserWarning: 
              *********************** WARNING ... ***********************
              {'missing'} AAD group is not on users.yml as a local group
              Please add it if needed
              *********************** WARNING ... ***********************
              
    warnings.warn(

-- Docs: docs.pytest.org/en/latest/warnings.html
=========================== short test summary info ============================
FAILED test_sync.py::GroupsTestCase::test_warning_checking_remote_group_not_in_local_groups
```

I understand probably the list of dictionaries I am sending as a parameters are not accepted or are not available for the types of data  `assertWarns()` expect?

Despite that, the message I expected (`{'missing'} AAD group is not on users.yml as a local group, Please add it if needed`) is shown, but I expect from this test pass.

What is the best way to use [`assertWarns()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertWarns).

If I use assertFalse, the test pass, although I am not sure if is the most specific/better assert I can use.

Comment: i guess `checking_aad_local_groups` returns list, and list is really not callable.  probably you have to do something like:  
```self.assertWarns(UserWarning, checking_aad_local_groups, AND HERE ARGUMENTS FOR FUNCTION)```

Comment: You are not using `assertWarns` correctly. Its second parameter is expected to be a `callable`. You are supplying the result of a call, namely a `list`. Did you mean: `self.assertWarns(UserWarning, checking_aad_local_groups, (data, groups))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `assertWarns(UserWarning, checking_aad_local_groups(...))` then you are calling `checking_aad_local_groups` and passing the result to `assertWarns`.  You want to give `assertWarns` a callable so that it can wrap it in the warning detection code.

```
self.assertWarns(UserWarning, checking_aad_local_groups, (data, groups))
```

Alternatively, you can use it as a context manager

```
with self.assertWarns() as w:
   checking_aad_local_groups(data, groups)
```